# Display line chart with connected dots using chartJS

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization, chart.js

I want to draw a chart like this using ChartJS. But I couldn't find a solution for connect first and last dots and show single unique dot inside that connected area. And also I need to style each dot with different colors. I tried exploring ChartJS documentation but couldn't find a solution. Is there any chart drawing library which has these features or how to do this with ChartJS?

[image]

Comment: can be done with chart.js.. no need for other chart drawing library..

Comment: @ɢʀᴜɴᴛ,Thanks. Can you tell me how to do it. I tried with chartjs but didn't success.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can create a [scatter chart](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/scatter.html#scatter-chart) instead of [line](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/line.html#line).

Here is an [example](https://jsfiddle.net/p4tyLgme/) :
<sup>( tried to replicate your given image amap )</sup>

```js
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
   type: 'scatter',
   data: {
      datasets: [{
         data: [{
            x: 1,
            y: 1
         }, {
            x: 3,
            y: 7
         }, {
            x: 6,
            y: 5
         }, { // add same data as the first one, to draw the closing line
            x: 1,
            y: 1
         }],
         borderColor: 'black',
         borderWidth: 1,
         pointBackgroundColor: ['#000', '#00bcd6', '#d300d6'],
         pointBorderColor: ['#000', '#00bcd6', '#d300d6'],
         pointRadius: 5,
         pointHoverRadius: 5,
         fill: false,
         tension: 0,
         showLine: true
      }, {
         data: [{
            x: 3.5,
            y: 4.5
         }],
         pointBackgroundColor: 'orange',
         pointBorderColor: 'darkorange',
         pointRadius: 10,
         pointHoverRadius: 10
      }]
   },
   options: {
      legend: false,
      tooltips: false,
      scales: {
         xAxes: [{
            ticks: {
               min: 0,
               max: 10
            },
            gridLines: {
               color: '#888',
               drawOnChartArea: false
            }
         }],
         yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
               min: 0,
               max: 8,
               padding: 10
            },
            gridLines: {
               color: '#888',
               drawOnChartArea: false
            }
         }]
      }
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="ctx"></canvas>
```

<sup>**note :** this is just an example, and you can customize it further to fit your need, following the [official documentation](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/line.html#dataset-properties).</sup>

Comment: This REALLY helped me figure out a chart I am trying to create!  Thanks GRUNT

Comment: Such a great answer - it's very unclear from the official docs that this stuff can be done in chartjs

Comment: +1 For the `showLine: true` option, in older versions of chart.js it wasn't needed, but after the update it is necessary.